# How do i find max combination from given result string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the output.

```
ID     Stack    
-----------------------------------
123    307290,303665,307285  
123    307290,307285,303424,303665  
123    307290,307285,303800,303665  
123    307061,307290
```

I want output like only last three row. The reason is in 1st output line stack column all three numbers are available in output line 2 and 3 stack column, so I don't need output line 1.

But the output lines 2,3,4 is different so I want those lines in my result.

I have tried doing it with `row_number()` and `charindex` but I'm not getting the proper result.

Thank you.

Comment: Storing multiple values in a single field is a bad idea and you are now facing the consequences of that decision (the person who made the decision should be strung up by their toes). I would imagine that a custom function might be your best bet here, but it's not going to be pretty or fast and it definitely won't be pretty or fast. It will be ugly and slow. It will also be painful and ugly and slow and definitely not pretty or fast. Definitely not pretty or fast.

Comment: Use a string-splitter function to break the column with multiple values into multiple rows. It should be easier to manipulate the values that way. But you still may need to do multiple steps (with temp tables to store intermediate results, or nested sub-selects or something).

Comment: The reason it will be ugly and slow is that for each record you will have to look at the stack, parse it, then analyze every other record in the table, parsing it's stack and determining if EVERY stack element in your current record is fully covered by any combination of stack elements in any other individual record. If you had a better schema like `id | stack_id | stack_elem` with each element of your `stack` going into the `stack_elem` column and an id to identify individual stacks for the `id`... then this would be a touch easier. Not fast, but faster and definitely prettier.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If >2012, it'll be much easier, but still ugly and slow.

Comment: I am using 2014.

Comment: I believe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617538/sql-server-sum-comma-separated-value-from-a-column

Comment: You really need to considering fixing this database structure.  Anything you hack together today will cause performance hits and pains, or completely break one day as there is no discernible order to this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the comments telling you to change your database's structure are right! You really should avoid comma separated values. This is breaking 1.NF and will be a pain in the neck forever.

The result of the second CTE might be used to shift all data into a new `1:n` related structure.

Something like this?

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,Stack VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (123,'307290,303665,307285')
,(123,'307290,307285,303424,303665')
,(123,'307290,307285,303800,303665')
,(123,'307061,307290');

WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,Stack
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowIndex
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(Stack,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) Casted 
    FROM @tbl
)
,DerivedDistinctValues AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
           ID
          ,Stack
          ,RowIndex
          ,StackNr.value('.','int') AS Nr
    FROM Splitted
    CROSS APPLY Casted.nodes('/x') AS A(StackNr)
)
SELECT ddv1.ID
      ,ddv1.Stack
FROM DerivedDistinctValues AS ddv1
FULL OUTER JOIN DerivedDistinctValues AS ddv2 ON ddv1.RowIndex<>ddv2.RowIndex
                                             AND ddv1.Nr=ddv2.Nr
WHERE ddv2.ID IS NULL
GROUP BY ddv1.ID,ddv1.Stack
```

This will be slow, especially with larger data sets.

Some explanation:

The first CTE will transform the CSV numbers to `<x>307290</x><x>303665</x>...` This can be casted to XML, which allows to generate a derived table returning all the numbers as rows. This happens in the second CTE calling the XQuery function `.nodes()`.

The last query will do a full outer join - each with each. All rows, where there is at least one row *without* a corresponding row are to be kept.

But I assume, that this might not work with each and any situation (e.g. circular data)

Comment: Thanks, this will help me.